# How do I remotely reset the WinRM service using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, winrm

When re-registering a configured PowerShell session with the same name as before, the WinRM service might (more often than not) need to be restarted.

My issue is that this needs to be done remotely in my environment.
Thus, this sequence of commands below will fail if not run locally...

```
Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {
  Unregister-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession' -Force
  Restart-Service WinRM -Force # This will of course kill the current WinRM connection 
  Register-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession'
}
```

Is there a safe way to do an `Unregister-PsSessionConfiguration`, using the same name later on, without the need of restarting the `WinRM` service?

A work around would, of course, be to run this as a `Scheduled Task` to keep the session doing the reset from being terminated.

As a note, you should always set up registered sessions with the option `-SecurityDescriptorSddl` to keep it from being accessed by any administrator.

Comment: A scheduled task is probably indeed the way to - to my knowledge there's no way to affect the registration changes without restarting the service

Comment: I had a look at closing all open PSSessions first, but that of course will also kill the remote session trying to restart `WinRM` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, `Scheduled Tasks` was the way to go...
To keep the code more readable, I've only provided some of the parameters needed to set up a scheduled task using PowerShell.

You won't be able to run this example straight of.

```
$Online = $null
while (!$Online) {# Make sure remote connection is possible first
  try {$Online = Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {$true} -ErrorAction Stop}
  catch {$Online = $false}
}

try {
  Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {# Kill WinRM (also killing this session)
    Unregister-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession' -Force

    $RestartWinRM = {# Code for restarting WinRM using Scheduled Task}

    Register-ScheduledTask `
      -TaskPath '.' -TaskName 'Restart WinRM' `
      -Action $RestartWinRM

    Start-ScheduledTask -TaskPath '.' -TaskName 'Restart WinRM' 
  }
}
catch {# The error when this session terminates
}

$Online = $null
while (!$Online) {# Make sure remote connection is possible again
  try {$Online = Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {$true} -ErrorAction Stop}
  catch {$Online = $false}
}

Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {# Register the session configuration again
  Register-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MS, this should be enough.

```
Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession' -Force
```

Ref: [MS Learn - Delete a session configuration and restart the WinRM service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/unregister-pssessionconfiguration?view=powershell-5.1)

So two Invokes **should** do the trick.

```
Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {
  Unregister-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession' -Force
}

# Wait for WinRM to start up

Invoke-Command 'RemoteServer' {
  Register-PsSessionConfiguration -Name 'MySession'
}
```

But it doesn't...
So I assume that restarting `WinRM` remotely using `Unregister-PsSessionConfiguration -Force` is blocked.